# Access remote domain using AJAX from extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension that AJAX's a particular page, and then will display notifications depending on what is on that page. (Using `webkitNotifications`)

This page is a ticketing system, and what I'm checking for is whether the user is logged in, and whether they have new tickets or not. More importantly, I don't own or have any control over the remote page.

I'm getting stuck because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Basically, when I attempt to AJAX the page, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://{{ Remote Site URL }}. Origin chrome-extension://gcagdmmcgmldhommhlckpbgdmlfojblp is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have never developed an extension for Chrome or any other browser, so I'm not sure about possible workaround off the top of my head.

I've tried looking through Google and SO for solutions but I can't seem to find anything that suits my needs.

Comment: Add `http://{{ Remote Site URL }}*` to the permissions field of `manifest.json` - see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Chrome extension documentation has a page dedicated to [cross-domain XHR](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).  Simply add a URL [`match pattern`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) that satisfies the site you wish to fetch as a permission to your manifest.  A good match pattern might look like

- `http://www.example.com/*`
- `*://www.example.com/*` (for both HTTP and HTTPS)
- `https://*.example.com/*` (for all subdomains of `example.com` over HTTPS)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution that I need!